# Transforming a weighted sum to another one with different weights

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Let $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ and $w_1, w_2, \dots, w_n$ be real numbers and $f_1 = x_1+\dots+x_n$ and $f_2 = w_1x_1+\dots+w_nx_n$. Is it possible to find a transformation $T$ which $T(f_1)=f_2$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Only if all the $w_i$'s are equal.

In general you need to know all the $x_i$'s to multiply them by different numbers.

Answer (score -1):

welcome to MSE. It is not clarified problem ,but I have a suggestion
$$f_1=1_{1\times n}X_{n\times 1}=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \end{pmatrix} 
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
x_1 \\x_2 &  \\
x_3  \\
\vdots & \\x_n\end{array} \right) $$ so $$f_2=T(f_1)$$ where $$\begin{pmatrix}
 w_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\0&w_2 & \cdots & 0\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
 0 & 0& \cdots & w_n \end{pmatrix} $$ so $$T(f_1)\\=1_{1 \times n}W_{n\times n}X_{n\times 1}\\=  \begin{pmatrix}
 w_1 & w_2 & \cdots & w_n \end{pmatrix} X_{n\times 1}\\=w_1x_1+w_2x_2+...+w_nx_n$$
you can rewrite $$T(f_1)=(W_{n\times n}1_{n\times 1})^TX_{n\times 1}$$ I mean $^t$  transpose

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your suggestion does not seem to respect the dimension. $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ are real numbers and not vectors.

Comment: @Mirar: but the resultant is like dot multiplying and its scalar.

Comment: I appreciate it if you could help me to understand. In your calculation, $f_{1}=IX$, where I is an $n \times n$ matrix and $X$ is a vector of size $n \times 1$, therefore $f_{1}$ will be of size $n \times 1$. Similarly, so will be $f_{2}$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Mirar: I am sorry for mistake about vector and matrix dimentions. I fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your effort @Khosrotash. I still believe that the calculation is inaccurate. You wrote $T(f_{1})=1_{1 \times n} W_{n \times n} X_{n \times 1}$ which to me (with your assumption on $f_{1}= 1_{1 \times n} X_{n \times 1}$) should be $T(f_{1})=1_{1 \times n} W_{n \times n} 1_{1 \times n} X_{n \times 1}$ instead. As you can see it is not correct (dimension-wise)

Comment: @Mirar: I did not tel $T(f_{1})=1_{1 \times n} W_{n \times n} 1_{1 \times n} X_{n \times 1}$!   but I did $T(f_1)\\=1_{1 \times n}W_{n\times n}X_{n\times 1}\\$

Comment: I did not say you did! What I said was, with your assumptions and settings, we cannot reach to your conclusion.